# Typescript error when deploying node js app on azure app service

Tags: typescript, azure

I have a node js app (developed using typescript) deployed on azure app services. The app has been running fine until now. I had to make some code changes and when I deployed the app, it failed with the below error

```
+ typescript@3.8.3
updated 1 package in 4.391s
Building Typescript files.

D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:79
        throw new Error("TypeScript requires an environment that provides a co
              ^
Error: TypeScript requires an environment that provides a compatible native Map implementation.
    at ts.Map (D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:79:15)
    at ts (D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:80:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:81:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc:2:1)
```

I looked at the logs from the previous successful deployment and noticed that the typescript version has changed from 3.6.4 to 3.8.3

```
+ typescript@3.6.4
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 4.284s
Building Typescript files.
```

I updated the dependencies in my package.json to force it to use 3.6.4. But that does not seem to have any impact and it continues using 3.8.3.

Any suggestions to get this fixed ?

Thanks

Comment: Try to upload your app in another instance of azure app service

Comment: Are the node runtimes the same versión? Map is a "recently" added Object to the standards so you need to have updated node runtime version or to have a lower typescript version. regards

Comment: @peterzinho16 Tried it on another instance of azure app service. Same error.

Comment: @HectorMartinez upgraded node and npm but still the same error.                                "node": ">=12.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.12.0"

Answer (score 0):

delete your node-modules directory,

in your package.json make sure you have

```
"dependencies" :  {
   "typescript" : "3.6.4"
}
```

then build. your package-lock.json should now have 3.6.4 which should be the only version installed. Unless you have typescript installed globally for some reason...

Comment: I tried deployment by upgrading the node and npm to higher version ("node": ">=12.0.0", "npm": ">=6.12.0" ) and leaving typescript to 3.8.3. Still the same error. I tried by lowering the node and npm version to "node": "=10.15.2",   "npm": "=6.4.1" and "typescript": "3.6.4", but azure still seem to be using typescript@3.8.3 and hence the same error.   Although azure uses the node and npm based on the package.json, it does not seem to be using the typescript version from package.json. :(

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue fixed by forcing my deployment script (deploy.sh) to install typescript@3.6.4.

```
npm install -g typescript@3.6.4
```